# NPM production and development on live server

Tags: node.js, git, npm

This might be a silly question but I am using `npm` first time in my project so I need to know best practice for this.

How do I manage `npm development` and `npm production` on local and production server?

As of now I run `npm run development` command when developing and save the compiled files along with other changes on `git`.

Before I pull all the changes on production server, I run `npm run production` command and commit on `git`. After that I pull the latest changes on production and then run `npm run development` on my local branch.

What are the best practice to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The ‘Best Practice’ is that you *don’t commit any compiled files*.

You should use `.gitignore` to ignore the folder that your files are compiled into. *But* before you do that, delete the folder and commit the deletion, so that Git understands those files are gone. Then add the folder to `.gitignore` and you can carry on.

On your local machine, you can run `npm run development`. Then on your production server, or on a build machine, you can run `npm run production`.

Comment: oh ok, so you run `npm run production` after every pull on production server, right?

Comment: Yup! The next step is to set your production server to do that automatically. My personal recommendation would be to look at something like [Buddy](https://buddy.works/), but there’s no requirement.